# how to insert a content over another content into a div

Tags: html

I'm trying to insert a chat script intro a div where it's already a img src and i want that chat to fit over it.

```
 <div id="g_image6" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top: 80%; width:                  
   22%; height: 60%; z-index:3">
  <div>
 <img src="images/content1.png" alt="" title="" border=0 width=100% height=100%>
  <script>here's the script</script>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the question is "how to insert a content over another content into a div" .... it was the title...

Answer (score 0):

Give the div an id...

```
<div id="chatscript">
<img src="images/content1.png" alt="" title="" border=0 width=100% height=100%>
</div>
```

Then with Jquery, replace the contents of the div with your script contents...

```
var yourscript = "<p>This is your chat data</p>";
$('#chatscript').html(yourscript);
```

But of course it depends on how youre getting the data..

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question, you want the image to be underneath the chat script?? Like as a background?

Comment: i want the image to be as a background of the div and the chat to be over it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the image as a background to the div instead of as a src tag? That way it will stay as a background to your script.

```
<div id="g_image6" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top: 80%; width: 22%; height: 60%; z-index:3">
<div style="background: url('images/content1.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
<script>script goes here</script>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't know if it's what you're looking for, but it sets the image to the background of your chat.